# Memory leak in Owin.AppBuilderExtensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, owin

I use OWIN + Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin (v.2.0.0.0) in Web application. I register UserManager/DbContext per web request, as widely recommended:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

but neither is ever disposed. I took a glance look into reflector and it seems like a bug in extension method:

```
public static IAppBuilder CreatePerOwinContext<T>(this IAppBuilder app, Func<IdentityFactoryOptions<T>, IOwinContext, T> createCallback) where T: class, IDisposable
{
    if (app == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("app");
    }
    if (createCallback == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("createCallback");
    }
    object[] args = new object[1];
    IdentityFactoryOptions<T> options = new IdentityFactoryOptions<T> {
        DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider()
    };
    IdentityFactoryProvider<T> provider = new IdentityFactoryProvider<T> {
        OnCreate = createCallback
    };
    options.Provider = provider;
    args[0] = options;
    app.Use(typeof(IdentityFactoryMiddleware<T, IdentityFactoryOptions<T>>), args);
    return app;
}
```

IdentityFactoryProvider has two callbacks - create and dispose, but dispose callback is not registered here. I also confirmed my suspicion with memory profiler.

I don't see Owin on codeplex/github (actually I thought it is open source), so I don't know where to ask my question: could anyone else confirm this is memory leak?
I'm not that sure because google says nothing about it, I expect it should be discussed everywhere, if this is a bug.

Comment: I took the liberty to forward this to the Microsoft team that handles this code.

Comment: It would be nice to hear their response, if any.

Comment: Last I heard, there were investigating the issue. The main problem is that the Identity code is not open source and it's kind of hard to create a pull request to fix it. There's a placeholder on codeplex at the moment but... nothing yet. It might be a hint that it would be open sourced eventually.

Comment: While the observation that a disposable per request object not being disposed is a bug, the lack of calling `Dispose` does not cause a memory leak or at least not a managed memory leak. `Dispose` will ensure that __unmanaged__ resources are released. Managed memory is freed by the garbage collector and not by a call to `Dispose`. If managed memory is "leaking" then it is because the OWIN framework permanently stores references to each new `DbContext` and `UserManager` prohibiting the garbage collector from freeing the memory when the request ends.

Answer (score 6):

I also have his issue, nothing that is registered with CreatePerOwinContext gets disposed. I'm using v2.1.

Here's a temporary fix which is working well for me as a work around until this lib is fixed. You basically have to manually register each of the types that use register with CreatePerOwnContext in the following class, and then at the end of your Startup procedure you register this custom class:

```
public sealed class OwinContextDisposal : IDisposable
{
    private readonly List<IDisposable> _disposables = new List<IDisposable>(); 

    public OwinContextDisposal(IOwinContext owinContext)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null) return;

        //TODO: Add all owin context disposable types here
        _disposables.Add(owinContext.Get<MyObject1>());
        _disposables.Add(owinContext.Get<MyObject2>());

        HttpContext.Current.DisposeOnPipelineCompleted(this);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var disposable in _disposables)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

At the end up your Startup process register this class:

```
 app.CreatePerOwinContext<OwinContextDisposal>(
      (o, c) => new OwinContextDisposal(c));
```

Now everything will get disposed of at the end of the request pipeline properly.

Answer (score 5):

The memory leak in `AppBuilderExtensions` class has been already fixed in latest version of `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` library ([2.2.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/)).

I have checked the code by using Reflector and also by putting a breakpoint into `Dispose()` methods of objects created by `AppBuilderExtensions.CreatePerOwinContext()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the logic for disposing the instances you create with `CreatePeOwinContext()` in the same callback you use to create this intances.
That is:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ClassIWantOneInstancePerContext>(ClassIWantOneInstancePerContext.Create);

        //other code...
    }
}
```

Then you only should care about to include a call to `DisposeOnPipelineCompleted()` within the callback used to instantiate your class. That is:

```
public class ClassIWantOneInstancePerContext
{
     //other code...

    public static ClassIWantOneInstancePerContext Create()
    {
        ClassIWantOneInstancePerContext TheInstance = new ClassIWantOneInstancePerContext();
        HttpContext.Current.DisposeOnPipelineCompleted(TheInstance);

        return TheInstance;
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to include the `Dispose()` method on your class definition!

Comment: This may look like odd reason, but I want to stay within  OWIN abstraction and don't want to reference System.Web...

Comment: This does introduce a dependenct on System.Web, but it definitely works!

Answer (score 0):

Usage : `app.CreatePerRequest<AuthorizationContext>();`

Extension Method :

```
public static IAppBuilder CreatePerRequest<T>(this IAppBuilder builder )where T:IDisposable
        {
            builder.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                var resolver = context.Get<IDependencyScope>();

                using (var instance = (T) resolver.GetService(typeof (T)))
                {
                    context.Set<T>(instance);
                    if (next != null)
                    {
                        await next();
                    }
                }

            });

            return builder;
        }
```

To Use Dependency Injection you have to configure owin : `app.UseScopePerOwinRequest(_dependencyResolver);` - This should be first middleware..

```
public static IAppBuilder UseScopePerOwinRequest(this IAppBuilder builder,IDependencyResolver resolver)
        {
            builder.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                using (var instance = resolver.BeginScope())
                {
                    context.Set<IDependencyScope>(instance);
                    if (next != null)
                    {
                        await next();
                    }
                }

            });

            return builder;
        }
```

And for above code to work you have to implement IDepedencyResolver with any container.

- The request comes in and new scope for request get created
- Within that scope you create other object.
- Use those objects in other middleware
- and when the scope is over, it get disposed.
- any objects within that scope which is not disposed also get disposed off.