# Handling Entity-Framework Context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

In the new `MVC-5` template there's a file at the `App_Start` folder called `Startup.Auth.cs` which contains this lines (along with some other data):

```
// Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

What does `a single instance per request` meen? and what is the difference between calling the `ApplicationDbContext` like this:

```
var context = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

and placing this declaration as a field in the `Controller class`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

Is there a preferred approach for handling the `context`? is a `singleton class` providing the `context` preffered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a convenient way of having a context object created whenever one of your action methods are called. You want a single instance per request because you want all of your objects to be attached to the same context instance. You also want the lifetime of your context to be the request lifetime.

If you were to use the second approach `private ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();` you would have to put that into every controller. You could create some sort of base controller that does the same thing and just inherit from your base controller.

Again it's just a convenience method used for demonstration.

Comment: So placing `private ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();` at the controller level will create an instance on every request? will that instance be disposed after the server responds?

Comment: No you should write a dispose method on your controller to dispose of the context. That's another convenience thing with the other technique.

Comment: won't I have to manually dispose of the context anyway before returning from an action?

Comment: Controllers implement IDisposable already. All you need to do is override it with your own implementation and call the base method.

Comment: So by creating an instance of the context like this: `var context = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();` I don't need to dispose of it explicitly?

Comment: Correct that context is managed by the controller as a feature of mvc

Comment: Could you please point me to any kind of document that explains this? I was looking for one but couldn't find one that mentioned that this object is self disposed and when.

Comment: The context is self disposed at the end of the request as a feature of the create method. Im on mobile but will dig up some sources when i have time

Comment: Is it really so? It seem that owin does NOT dispose the stuff created! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378856/memory-leak-in-owin-appbuilderextensions

Comment: @LukasK The intended effect is that it does :) I haven't looked into that enough to comment on the bug.

Comment: The bug should be fixed in version 2.2, so I hope it will work... http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/2374

Comment: How on earth was Identity released with an ApplicationDbContext which doesn't dispose per request??

Comment: @epalm When the app pool recycles the memory gets flushed anyway, so the problem would likely only surface in higher load circumstances in the first place. Also note that you would never hit this problem if you used your own dependency injector (which is what this is used for) or no injection at all (also very common).